# Copy Excel Row if Cell is equal to a value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy and paste into a different workbook and spread that data over different sheets inside of the new workbook.  I've got my VBA working, but it only works about 25% of the time.  I continually get an error on "Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed".

Here is the script:

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim i As Range
    For Each i In Range("A1:A1000")

        Windows("data_1.xls").Activate
        Sheets("data_1").Activate
        If i.Value = 502 Then
            i.Select
            ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Windows("DataOne.xls").Activate
            Sheets("502").Range("A39").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        End If
        If i.Value = 503 Then
            ........
        End If
     Next i
End Sub
```

The failure happens on `i.Select` every time.  Do I need to bring `Next i` up to the end of every `End If`?

Comment: You don't need to use select at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Activate, Select, or copy/paste if you just want to transfer values.

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim i As Range
    Dim srcBook as Workbook
    Dim destBook as Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set srcBook = Workbooks("data_1.xls")
    Set destBook = Workbooks("DataOne.xls")

    For Each i In srcBook.Sheets("data_1").Range("A1:A1000")
        Select Case i.Value
            Case 502
                destBook.Sheets("502").Range("A39").End(xlUp). _
                    Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = i.EntireRow.Value
            Case 503
                destBook.Sheets("503").Range("A39").End(xlUp). _
                    Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = i.EntireRow.Value
            Case 504
                'etc
            Case Else 
                'do nothing/ or do something for non-matching
        End Select
     Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This could maybe be further simplified if I knew more about your `If/Then` structure and the destination of the values (are they all going to a sheet name in the same file, which corresponds to the value of `i`?  If so, this could be even more simple.

I am curious why you're looping a range of 1000 rows, but only writing to a range of A39 (`.End(xlUp)`)...

**Updated from comments:**

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim i As Range
    Dim srcBook as Workbook
    Dim destBook as Workbook
    Set srcBook = Workbooks("data_1.xls")
    Set destBook = Workbooks("DataOne.xls")

    For Each i In srcBook.Sheets("data_1").Range("A1:A1000")
        destBook.Sheets(Cstr(i)).Range("A:A").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0). _
            EntireRow.Value = i.EntireRow.Value
     Next i
End Sub
```

You probably don't need to worry about `ScreenUpdating` with this size of an array, and using this direct method to write from/to the destination, it's not nearly as resource-intensive as continuously selecting, activating, copying/pasting and then selecting again, etc.

Comment: This is great thanks.  First question you asked about If/Then: They are all going to a new file with sheets that are in fact the same value as i yes.  Second question: The data is scraped from an website and only downloads in long excel sheet.  Each of those numbers corresponds to a company site so while the data is 750 to 900 cells deep on the original spreadsheet, I'd like the data to be more readable on their own sheets.  Make sense?

Comment: If the files arent' already open, you would have gotten an `Index out of Range` error on the `Set srcBook` or `Set destBook` lines.

Comment: A good example of how to do this the right way. Gets my vote - although I think that toggling `ScreenUpdating` is always good practice in any VBA script - you never know how things will grow in the future, and the flashing screen never makes the application look better!

Comment: @Floris I added the screenupdating :)

Comment: So this is working and reading the info really efficiently, however, it's only copying the `502` over to every cell in the row.  Literally, I'm just getting `502` for the entire row, it's not grabbing any of the information adjacent.  I'm thinking that's from `EntireRow.Value = i.Value` as the `i.Value` is simply `502`.  How can I grab the adjacent information?

Comment: Try `... = i.EntireRow.Value`. Revision above :)

Comment: I'm very new to VBA - how can I modify this to copy the row *beneath* each case of, say, "502"? So every time it finds "502" it will copy the row beneath that cell. I've tried just setting a variable as `i+1` but I think I'm doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @pez in this code, `i` is a `Range` object, not an integer, `i+1` therefore may give you unexpected results or errors. To best assist you (if you haven't done so already) it's advised that you ask a new question. This way you can show the code you're using, describe your specific problem(s), and also gets the most exposure to people who will be able to help. Feel free to tag me in the comments and I will try to take a look at it if I can.

Answer (score 1):

When you activate another sheet/window, you confuse the loop. The next `i` ends up referring to the next cell in the wrong sheet, which may have no value in.

If you do have to `Activate`, make sure you go back to the original sheet before the next round in the loop. Which means you REALLY need `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of your sub, and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end...

Comment: Just to add an idea of how to fix it, don't use 'active' methods

Comment: Would you put the `Application.ScreenUpdating` inside of the for loop or just at the beginning and end of the sub?  @PortlandRunner I've tried to remove the `i.Select` and just use `i.Rows` to avoid the 'active' method as you mention, but this still has the same Run-time error.

Comment: What I meant was don't use ActiveSheet, ActiveWorkbook, or ActiveCell.  Define the workbook and cell directly as a variable.

Comment: @Benjooster - put `Application.Screenupdating` as the first and last lines of the sub, outside of the `For` loop. Things will be much faster, and there won't be the annoying flashing of the screen.